# Distributed Session for Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

What are the minimum steps requires to config Spring Security Java to provide a database stored session implementation. Basically I want to use Session ID with Cookies and a JDBC based Session Implementation. It seems that I have to implement a custom Session Registry but could not be sure that what I need extra implementations to provide a database based Session implementation.

(I am using Spring Security RC2)

Comment: And what has that to do with Spring Security? That depends on your servlet container and not on Spring Security. The `SessionRegistry` in Spring Security has a whole different meaning and use-case then distributed sessions.

Comment: I considered that Spring Security would be responsible to both session management and security. It seems that there is a fundamental mistake in my understanding. Am I wrong?

Comment: Correct... Spring doesn't manage your session that is the task of your Servlet Container (as it it part of the specification), how to change the way that it persists can in general be found in the documentation. The `SessionRegistry` in Spring is there for its concurrent session-management support and has nothing to do with storing state.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Don't you think that this is an enhancement? Because all framework does not depend on Servlet Specification for example standalone applications.

Comment: Additional provided SecurityContextRepository implementations are scheduled as part of Spring Security 4. See https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rob Winch and M. Deinum clarified my question and explained that currently this is not possible with Spring. However there is [an issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-2346) related to my question. I have decided to use Servlet API and Container Session Management.

There is a [Spring Session](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session) project which is being implemented by Rob Winch currently.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented [RESTfull distributive system](https://github.com/azee/template-api) using Spring Security and MongoDB.
Here are [filters](https://github.com/azee/template-api/tree/master/template-rest/src/main/java/com/mycompany/template/security), [config](https://github.com/azee/template-api/blob/master/template-rest/src/main/resources/securityContext.xml) and [service](https://github.com/azee/template-api/blob/master/template-service/src/main/java/com/mycompany/template/services/UserService.java).

Please feel free to fork and push.

Comment: If you are using a Jersey Security - you can override Session Repository and use Hazelcast or Mongo (Hazelcast will work faster).